# Некорректно отрабатывает код

Tags: php

Пытаюсь создать PHP корзину, но он ведет себя некорректно. На этапе добавления присутствует проверка, если товар существует в $_SESSION, то просто добавить к нему единицу. Если же товар отсутствует, то полностью записать информацию. Проблема в том, что данный код, а точнее, функция set() просто добавляет в сессию id и количество предмета, а сумму игнорирует. И как бы сделать так, чтобы при добавлении товара, каждый раз создавалась отдельная строка в массиве $_SESSION? Далее код:

```
class Cart {

        public function init(){
                if(!isset($_SESSION)){
                        session_start();
                      }
                      if(!isset($_SESSION['card_items'])){
                        $_SESSION['card_items'] = array();
                      }
                    }

        public function set($id, $price){
          if($_SESSION['card_items']['id'] = $id)
          {
            $_SESSION['card_items']['qty']++;
          }
          else
          {
            $_SESSION['card_items']['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['card_items']['price'] = $price;
            $_SESSION['card_items']['qty'] = 1;
          }
        }

        public function get(){
                foreach ($_SESSION as $temp){
                        //echo $temp."<br />";
                        print_r($temp);
                }
        }

}
$cart = new Cart;
$cart->init();
$cart->set(5, 2000);
$cart->get();
```

Бывает. Проблема с присвоением была. Здесь я не проверял условие, а присваивал переменную.

```
$_SESSION['card_items']['id'] = $id
```

а надо

```
$_SESSION['card_items']['id'] === $id
```

Минус одна проблема. Теперь как создать присвоение каждому товару новую строку в массиве?

Comment: Для его плодить одинаковые значения. когда можно их приплюсовать к тем, что есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Cart {

    public function __constructor()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['card_items'])) {
            $_SESSION['card_items'] = [];
        }
    }

    public function set($id, $price)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['card_items'])) {
            $_SESSION['card_items'][$id]['qty']++;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['card_items'][$id] = ['price' => $price, 'qty' => 1];
        }
    }

    public function get()
    {
        foreach ($_SESSION as $temp) {
            //echo $temp."<br />";
            print_r($temp);
        }
    }

}

$cart = new Cart();
$cart->set(5, 2000);
$cart->set(5, 2000);
$cart->get();
```

Получаем

> Array (
>       [5] => Array
>           (
>               [price] => 2000
>               [qty] => 2
>           )
>   )

Comment: constructor) Это типа от ленивых защита?

Comment: @Алексей, это от забывчивости защита. Метод `init` вы можете и не вызвать, а конструктор сам вызывается.

Comment: @ArchDaemon, Я в курсе. Просто не раз сталкивался, что на форумах или иных ресурсах заведомо делают очевидные ошибки, чтобы думали, а не копипастили. Как с тобой можно связаться?

Comment: @Алексей, никак. Задаёте вопрос, я или кто-то другой на него отвечает. Тут так принято

Comment: Принцип единой ответственности изнасилован. Остался только OLID :)

Comment: Я Вас внимательно слушаю. Где я сделал неправильно?

Comment: Вы смешали объект типа Корзина с хранилищем типа Сессия. На самом деле использовать их в одном классе неправильно.